# compass vertical rhythm not working

Tags: css, sass, vertical-alignment, compass-sass

I'm having a problem with the newest version of compass (0.12.2) and sass (3.1.20) where the vertical alignment mixins are not taking effect. When trying to validate the generated css with `compass validate`, it fails on the `compass/reset` include, as well as the border-radius mixin among others.

The code for the scss file in question can be found here in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3186271). The errors I receive on validation are [here](https://gist.github.com/3186286). To see what the website looks like, go to [bitlimn.com](http://www.bitlimn.com). The vertical spacing should be 1.5x, but it looks to be 1x.

Basically, I don't see some of the code. It worked before I upgraded my compass and sass gems.  Can anyone help me get back to fully functional compass/sass stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I found the answer. I was using a mixin "establish-baseline" inside the `html` block when the mixin source uses the `html` block itself. Essentially, I was doing this:

```
html {
    html {...} // Mixin
    ...
}
```

Lesson learned: always read the source of functions/mixins that you use before using them.